# Differentiating a series in maple

Tags: complex-analysis, maple

I am trying to get the third derivative of a Laurent series in Maple, while keeping it in series form, but it isn't giving me what I need. Here is the photo of what I am trying to do:

[image]

It might look like it cut off, but that's really the end of the problem, the third derivative says it is 0, when really it isn't. It also says it is 0 for the first derivative too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `diff` evaluates derivative of an expression, but your `l1` is actually an operator. So you need to either evaluate it in `z` to make it an expression that `diff` understands, like

`diff(l1(z),z$3);`

or, you can invoke the `D` that can calculate derivatives of operators, like this

`D[(1$3)](l1);`

Alternative solution would be to define `l1` already as an expression:

`l1:=5*I/(z-I)^6+5/(z-I)^5+2*exp(3*I)*sum((3^(n-6)*(z-I)^(n-6))/n!,n=0..infinity);`
`diff(l1,z$3);`

I am using the classic worksheet notation, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Is there any way to get it to leave it in the series notation though? By doing this, it expands the series and eliminates it.

Comment: @Heavenly96 Yes, use `Sum` instead of `sum`, i think.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much!

Comment: @Heavenly96 You are welcome. By the way, there is a proposal for Maple stack exchange site here: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/107315/maple where questions like this could be asked one day hopefuly. Feel free to support it :)